# Сохранить словарь в файл в json формате

Tags: python, windows, json, файлы, python-3.x

Создать словарь из 5 пар ключ:значение (Готово)

И сохранить это словарь в формате json (Вроде готово)

Сохранить в в текстовый файл  (output.txt) (Не готово)

```
json.dumps({"Login":"dima",
                "Password":123,
                "email":123123,
                "Country":"Russia",
                "City":"Moscow"},sort_keys=True)
```

Answer (score 2):

`json.dumps()` возвращает текст, который можно в файл сохранить:

```
import pathlib

pathlib.Path("путь").write_text(text, encoding="utf-8")
```

или напрямую [вызвать `json.dump()`, чтобы сразу на лету в файл сохранять](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#json.dump):

```
import json

with open("путь", "w", encoding="utf-8") as file:
    json.dump(data, file)
```